# Enlightenment on Lion - make default WM

Tags: window-manager, x11

I ran the Enlightenment e16.dmg file from here, http://trac.enlightenment.org/e/wiki/MACOSX , it works pretty good, but it runs on top of the mac osx default Window Manager (Quartz Compositor? i think its called).  Is there a way to just run the enlightenment manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean, booting into an X11 powered Window Manager instead of the Finder and Quartz? No, this is not possible (unless you install Linux of course and boot this directly).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Aqua and Quartz-wm (the X11 implementation) can't be separated, if someone is a glutton for punishment, then they could get XFree86 to work, like was outlined in this thread, http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=21116 .  But then you can't run native Mac apps which try to communicate with quart-wm, so its kind of pointless.